# WPF blink an ellipse fill animation

Tags: wpf

I was looking at this excellent post:
[How do I make an ellipse blink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457892/how-do-i-make-an-ellipse-blink)
Is there a way to not have the blink fade and instead just change the color immediately with no fade?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `DiscreteColorKeyFrame`. Set the  `KeyTime` to specify when you want it to trigger.

Here is an example of a blinking `Ellipse`. `Fill` alternates between Red and Blue every second

```
<Ellipse Fill="Red">
    <Ellipse.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                      Duration="0:0:2"
                                                      FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                                      RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Red"/>
                                <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Blue"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>                    
        </EventTrigger>
    </Ellipse.Triggers>
</Ellipse>
```